# Using foursquare API to get lat lon from addresses

Tags: python, api, geolocation, foursquare

In a recent project I used foursquare to find info about a list of venues in a city and it got me thinking.  Python and foursquare (using categories) could really help me with another project, but the data set is entirely addresses, no lat lon.

In everything I've seen online, you can get lat lon from venue name, but not from address.  In the code chunks I've been able to dig up, they use nominatim or google for geolocating *before* entering in the lat lon into foursquare, which kind of seems silly, but for the life of me I can't find the procedure for getting lat lon out of an address through a foursquare api.  Foursquare has much more relaxed limitations on calls than google or especially nominatim.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or have a code block that gets lat lon from a foursquare api based on address (street address, city, zip) alone?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get lat/lon from foursquare API, but there is a simple way with using `geopy` library.

To geolocate a query to an address and coordinates:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")

location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")

print(location.address)
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, ...

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to get a *lot* of locations geocoded as well as get their business category at the same time, which nominatim doesn't have.  :(

Comment: @J.Alexander you can use after that `foursquare` pypi package to get any foursquare's information using this coordinates:

```python
client = foursquare.Foursquare(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')

client.venues.search(params={'query': 'coffee', 'll': '40.7233,-74.0030'})
```
See https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare